# Downcasting trouble

Tags: c++

This is my first experience with downcasting in C++ and I just can't understand the problem.

`AInstruction` and `CInstruction` inherit from `AssemblerInstruction`.
`Parser` takes the info in its ctor and creates one of those derived instruction types for its `mInstruction` member (accessed by `getInstruction`). In the program, a method of the base `AssemblerInstruction` class is used, for happy polymorphism.

But when I want to test that the `Parser` has created the correct instruction, I need to query the derived instruction members, which means I need to downcast `parser.getInstruction()` to an `AInstruction` or `CInstruction`.

As far as I can tell this needs to be done using a bunch of pointers and references. This is how I can get the code to *compile*:

```cpp
TEST(ParserA, parsesBuiltInConstants)
{
    AssemblerInstruction inst = Parser("@R3", 0).getInstruction();
    EXPECT_EQ(inst.getInstructionType(), AssemblerInstruction::InstructionType::A);
    AssemblerInstruction* i = &(inst);
    AInstruction* a = dynamic_cast<AInstruction*>(i);

    EXPECT_EQ(a->getLine(), "R3");
}
```

Running this gives this error:
`unknown file: error: SEH exception with code 0xc0000005 thrown in the test body.`

And stepping through the code, when the debugger is on the final line of the function, `a` is pointing to
`0x00000000 <NULL>`.

I imagine this is an instance where I don't have a full enough understanding of C++, meaning that I could be making a n00b mistake. Or maybe it's some bigger crazy problem. Help?

### Update

I've been able to make this work by making `mInstruction` into a (dumb) pointer:

```cpp
// in parser, when parsing
mInstructionPtr = new AInstruction(assemblyCode.substr(1), lineNumber);

// elsewhere in AssemblerInstruction.cpp
AssemblerInstruction* AssemblyParser::getInstructionPtr() { return mInstructionPtr; } 

TEST(ParserA, parsesBuiltInConstants)
{
    auto ptr = Parser("@R3", 0).getInstructionPtr();
    AInstruction* a = dynamic_cast<AInstruction*>(ptr);
    EXPECT_EQ(a->getLine(), "R3");
}
```

However I have trouble implementing it with a `unique_ptr`:
(I'm aware that `mInstruction` (non-pointer) is redundant, as are two types of pointers. I'll get rid of it later when I clean all this up)

```cpp
class AssemblyParser
{
public:
    AssemblyParser(std::string assemblyCode, unsigned int lineNumber);
    AssemblerInstruction getInstruction();
    std::unique_ptr<AssemblerInstruction> getUniqueInstructionPtr();
    AssemblerInstruction* getInstructionPtr();

private:
    AssemblerInstruction mInstruction;
    std::unique_ptr<AssemblerInstruction> mUniqueInstructionPtr;
    AssemblerInstruction* mInstructionPtr;
};


// in AssemblyParser.cpp

// in parser as in example above. this works fine.
mUniqueInstructionPtr = make_unique<AInstruction>(assemblyCode.substr(1), lineNumber);

// this doesn't compile!!!
unique_ptr<AssemblerInstruction> AssemblyParser::getUniqueInstructionPtr()
{
    return mUniqueInstructionPtr;
}
```

In `getUniqueInstructionPtr`, there is a squiggle under `mUniqueInstructionPtr` with this error:

> 'std::unique_ptr<AssemblerInstruction,std::default_delete>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<AssemblerInstruction,std::default_delete> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

What!? I haven't declared any functions as deleted or defaulted!

Comment: A possibly related issue you should research: [What is object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Answer (score 2):

You can not downcast an object to something which doesn't match it's dynamic type. In your code,

```
 AssemblerInstruction inst = Parser("@R3", 0).getInstruction();
```

`inst` has a fixed type, which is `AssemblerInstruction`. Downcasting it to `AInstruction` leads to undefined behavior - manifested as crash - because that is not what it is.

If you want your `getInstruction` to return a dynamically-typed object, it has to return a [smart] pointer to base class, while constructing an object of derived class. Something like that (pseudo code):

```
 std::unique_ptr<AssemblerInstruction> getInstruction(...) {
      return std::make_unique<AInstruction>(...);
 }
```

Also, if you see yourself in need of downcasting object based on a value of a class, you are doing something wrong, as you are trying to home-brew polymorphism. Most of the times it does indicate a design flaw, and should instead be done using built-in C++ polymorphic support - namely, virtual functions.

Comment: Worth to mention that even if `getInstruction();` returns `AInstruction` or `CInstruction`, [it was sliced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) to `AssemblerInstruction`. I suppose this is where OP's confusion comes from.

Comment: Thanks @Yksisarvinen. This seems like the problem, but that doesn't mean it solves the problem because I don't understand casting/slicing well enough. Sounds like maybe `mInstruction` should be a *pointer* to an `AssemblerInstruction`? Would that prevent slicing?

Comment: @JonathanTuzman This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing

Comment: @JonathanTuzman Yes, seems that Sergey already updated the answer to include that with returning a smart pointer.

Comment: Thanks very much Sergey. I'm about to try implementing this and will mark it as an answer if (when!) it works. I did want to inquire into your last point. My application code never downcasts, it indeed uses the return of `Parser.getInstruction()` to call a virtual `AssemblerInstruction::getMachineCode`. Only in my unit tests, where I want to test what kind of instruction the parser created, completely independent of how an instruction produces its machine code, do I need to downcast to access the otherwise private members of the instructions (which only have getters for testing). Thoughts?

Comment: @JonathanTuzman up to you, different people have different expectations from unit tests. Some want them to test as white box, and others want them to test as black box. In my mind, both approaches are valid.